# Check if PM2 daemon is running and resurrect

Tags: ubuntu, cron, pm2

There were some recent problems on Ubuntu server due to low RAM. The server didn't reboot but PM2 crashed.

To avoid such situations in future, I'm looking for a way to check if PM2 daemon is running and resurrect it automatically if it's not. It is supposed to be a Cron job.

Can `pm2 resurrect` every minute be considered  a good solution, or it introduces too much overhead? What's the proper way to do this?